# How to change the activity to NOW PLAYING type upon clicking a selected song from a List then playing the song

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-music-player

I am trying to create a streaming app. I have been able to play songs using the PLAY/PAUSE button. But I am unable to get a song to play from a list of song and also change the DISPLAYING ACTIVITY to show the one with play-pause-stop-etc.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class playerInterface extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imagePlayPause;
    private TextView textCurrentTime, textTotalDuration;
    private SeekBar playerSeekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static String toPlay;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_interface);

        imagePlayPause = findViewById(R.id.imagePlayPause);
        textCurrentTime = findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.textTotalTimeDuration);
        playerSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);


        imagePlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });

        prepareMediaPlayer();
    }

    // this method aims at selecting a song when called from another java class
    public static void prepareMediaPlayer(int number){
        switch (number){
            case 1: toPlay = "https://www.blablabla1.mp3";
                break;
            case 2: toPlay = "https://www.blablabla2.mp3";
                break;
            case 3: toPlay = "https://www.blablabla3.mp3";
                break;
            default: toPlay = "https://www.blablabla4.mp3";
                break;
        }
    }

    // this method plays the song from the internet
    public void prepareMediaPlayer(){
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(toPlay); // url of music file
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        }catch (Exception exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I have tried the code below (from another activity), but it doesn't work.

```
     public void egwuOsadabe(View view){
        playerInterface.prepareMediaPlayer(3); // this aims at selecting a particular song upon click egwuOsadebe
        redirectActivity(this, playerInterface.class); // this aims at changing the activity to playerInterface.class (the code above).
    }
```

Comment: how do you redirect the activity? Did you try the normal method of opening an activity?

Comment: I used "Intent". This works, but playing a selected song upon opening is where the problem lies.

Comment: When you call prepareMediaPlayer() , i dont see you giving the orders to play any song

Comment: If the following plays a song correctly if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar(); } then maybe you should try a similar approach when opening the activity